# Can I merge two files into one in a version control?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Let's say I have two files with two classes, `A` and `B`. At some moment, it appears that the class `B` is used only inside class `A`, and it makes perfect sense, from the point of view of the code design, to put `B` *inside* `A` and declare it private.

Right now, if I have to do such task, I would simply copy the source code from one file to another, and then delete the now empty file. The drawback is that the version control history is not exactly lost, but cannot be obviously discovered any longer.

For instance, for anyone who blames the source code of `B`, it would look like I created the class from scratch, and the person would need to go and see the actual commit to understand what really happened, and then check the history of the removed file. By comparison, if I simply move the file, version control shows that the source code had a bunch of changes, then was moved, then had other changes.

Is there a way to merge two files (in either SVN or Git) in a way that the history would be preserved?

Naturally, when I try to Google it, I get a lot of results about merging branches, and I can't find how to make Google understand that I'm talking about a different merging.

Comment: Not directly..... might consider rewriting history so that instead of starting B as a separate file, it is started inside A from the beginning... but every time you modified B you will get a conflict so that you move the code from B to A.... not too difficult in itself, but tedious, if history is long.... and you are rewriting history, of course.

Comment: Let me describe the recipe as an answer

Comment: Is the history of these two files shared history?

Comment: E.g. have the commits for each file been pushed?

Comment: I'm wondering if renaming each file to C in separate branches and then merging them would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose that the first revision where B showed up in the project is X:

```
git rebase -i X~
# change the first revision to say edit (or e) in the text editor, save and exit
# git will go straight to the first revision where X shows up
# open A, copy B code in a way that makes it compile and so on
git add A
git rm B
git rebase --continue

# from now on, this is what you do every time a conflict comes up
git checkout REBASE_HEAD -- . # put everything exactly like it was in the revision we are rebasing
# open A... there should be no B code
# open B
# copy B code into A and make it compile
git add A
git rm B
git rebase --continue
```

Until it is finished... at that time, you should have a full history of B having grown inside A from the beginning.